# Wordpress - Is it okay to add new column to the existing db table?

Tags: database, wordpress

I need to store phone number on Comments. I know I can use meta field and be saved in `wp_commentmeta` table. But will reduce database size if it's in 1 table.

So, can I add like `phone_no` column to `wp_comments` table? Will it affect the way WordPress works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It will not break the Wordpress if you add a column, but you will not reduce size by doing so, and I think you should use wp_commentmeta.